# How get eraIndex by blockNumber?

Tags: eraindex, blocknumber, date

How can I get the eraIndex by having a blockNumber, or get date of an era? whichever works.

like:

```
   const eraIndex = getEraIndex(blockNumber);
```

or

```
   const date = getDate(eraIndex);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do is the following:

- Convert the relevant blockNumber to a hash
- Since runtime changes across upgrades, we get an instance of the API at a specific point
- Perform the query against `staking.aciveEra`, which returns an Option
- Check if the option is Some or None, we don't want to unwrap None
- Display the pertinent details

In code-form against the JS API, tested as-is on Polkadot -

```js
// the blockNumber we wish to query for
const blockNumber = 9608858;

// get the blockhash and API instance at this point of the chain
const blockHash = await api.rpc.chain.getBlockHash(blockNumber);
const apiAt = await api.at(blockHash);

// retrieve the activeEra
const activeEraOpt = await apiAt.query.staking.activeEra();

if (activeEraOpt.isSome) {
  const { index, start } = activeEraOpt.unwrap();
  
  console.log(`${index.toString()} started at ${new Date(start.unwrap().toNumber()).toString()}`);
} else {
  // there has been nothing at this point
  console.log('no activeEra found')
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jaco, you are awesome. Is there similar apis to get the start time of a specific era. const date=getEraStartTime(eraIndex);

Comment: Te state is not indexed by time, only blockHash. Since the state doesn't carry any information not pertinent to future block execution, this mapping is not available. You would need to track the events through the chain to find the start and then get the timestamp. (This is really for indexers)

Answer (score 5):

To get the era of a block, you can look at the `ActiveEra` storage item in [Staking](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/7a09b82/frame/staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#L302), and just query it at a particular block.

If you want to map the other way, era to block, you will need to index the chain for when the eras change, since an era actually corresponds to a range of blocks.

The [Sidecar staking controller](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/blob/master/src/controllers/pallets/PalletsStakingProgressController.ts) is a great place to look for how to derive staking related information. This particular question is handled by the internal function [`deriveSessionAndEraProgress`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/blob/db74ab49fcf948f44332568c57958ff85630c288/src/services/pallets/PalletsStakingProgressService.ts#L128).